# 3d printer drip problem

Tags: prusa-i3, pla, extruder, calibration, hotend

I have a problem with my 3d printer. When I am printing, the printer seems to drip. 
I am very confused because I never saw this before and I do not know what to do.

I attach a picture of it.

Why does this happen?

Thank you very much for yours ideas.

DATA:

- Printer: Anet A8
- Material: PLA
- Temperature: 200ºC

I Have enable retraction and I tried to disable it without changes...

[image: Image Drip]

Comment: Closely watch those 2-3 first layers and you'll have some good ideas about what's happening (or what is not happening).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two theories to offer.

**It is really dripping**.  If this is the case, the likely culprit is a loose part in the hot-end, namely the nozzle/heating block coupling, or the heating block/heat break one.  If this is the case, you should be able to see it by visually inspecting the part.  The solution in this case is to fully disassemble the parts, clean them thoroughly of any remaining plastic, and reassembling them *while hot*.  This is essential, as parts that are assembled cold have the tendency to come loose when heated (due to thermal expansion).

**It is overextruding**, and the nozzle collect and drag around the excessive plastic, until the blob is big enogh to detach and remain on the bed.  If this is the case, then you should [calibrate your extruder](https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/how-to-calibrate-your-extruder), and the [nozzle height](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=L6GJWHwrTmY).

Comment: You are right.

There is a leak of PLA on top of the heating block.

So I'll have to disassemble it :-(

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Jnavero - have a google around for how to disassemble the hot end.  The heat break expecially, that you will have to unscrew, is rather fragile.  Even if the part is loose, you may have to warm it up before disassembly, as the cold plastic may act as glue.